# To Post on friend's wall using feed dialog in sdk 3.5

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to post on the wall or send a private message to a friend.. I am using the latest SDK 3.5. I read that we should use the feed dialog to perform it.

my Code

```
private void publishFeedDialog() {
    try{
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");//title 
        params.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");//caption 
        params.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");

        WebDialog feedDialog = (
                new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(InviteParticipantsActivity.this,
                    Session.getActiveSession(),
                    params))
                .setOnCompleteListener(null)
                .build();
            feedDialog.show();
}
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

This code will post it on my wall but I am looking to post it on a friends wall or send a message.

I have all the details such as the name and id of the target user.

Comment: Take a look at this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907788/show-facebook-share-dialog/18909008#18909008

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
params.putString("to", "TARGET Facebook USER ID");
```

To post on your friends wall Add the parameter "to"

Comment: please refer to this link I am getting an error  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21678055/an-error-occured-while-posting-to-friends-wall-using-facebook-android-sdk-3-6-n?noredirect=1#comment32770939_21678055

Comment: Can we put multiple ids to share with multiple friends? If not how can we share text with multiple friends?

Answer (score -1):

Use below code.
Use setTo() method where you have to pass the ID of the friend as parameter .

```
 WebDialog feedDialog =( new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(getApplicationContext(), Session.getActiveSession(), null).setTo(ID)).setOnCompleteListener(null).build()
                feedDialog.show();
```

Comment: you can post on a friends wall.. I am sure about it

Comment: @contactmeandroid you can see this link http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/06/26/october-2013-platform-changes/

Comment: read it carefully it says " Please use the Feed Dialog for posting."

Comment: i got that.. but it takes only one id at a time.. any idea for sending group messages? I tried comma separated id's butdidn't work

Comment: @contactmeandroid in setTo method you can pass comma separated ids.     String ids = idList.get(0);
for (int i = 1; i < idList.size(); i++) {
 ids = ids + "," + idList.get(i);
 } where idList is list of ids. It worked for me.

Comment: Instead of posting to wall can we send a private message using feed dialog?

Comment: @contactmeandroid  this link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10764381/send-private-message-to-my-friends-using-my-android-application

Comment: @Madhu I can't post to multiple ids, I tried with the comma:          .setTo("677718938956578,420195354761298")
are you sure? This is all:
     WebDialog feedDialog = (
         new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(QuestionsActivity.this,
             Session.getActiveSession(),
             params))
         .setTo("677718938956578,420195354761298")
         .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
   LONG STUFF
         })
         .build();

Comment: @Accollativo Do you post to multiple ids.If yes ,will you please give the code.

Comment: @Sunny no, It's not possible. If you find some trick please tell me :)