# An Error occured while posting to Friends wall using Facebook android sdk 3.6 (newest)

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I am getting following error when posting to friends wall using Facebook Android sdk

[image]

Here is how I have written posting code.

```
private void publishFeedDialog() {
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
        params.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
        params.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
        params.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
        params.putString("picture", "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");
        params.putString("to", "xxxxx81890xxxxx");

        WebDialog feedDialog = (
            new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(this,
                Session.getActiveSession(),
                params))
            .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {


                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                        FacebookException error) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                     if (error == null) {
                            // When the story is posted, echo the success
                            // and the post Id.
                            final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                            if (postId != null) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Posted story, id: "+postId,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                // User clicked the Cancel button
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), 
                                    "Publish cancelled", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                            // User clicked the "x" button
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), 
                                "Publish cancelled", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            // Generic, ex: network error
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), 
                                "Error posting story", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                }

            })
            .build();
        feedDialog.show();
    }
```

when I remove this line

```
params.putString("to", "xxxxx381890xxxxx");
```

from above code,it is successfully posted on my wall. can anyone suggest me how to fix this issue ? I really didnt understand where I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Logcat:

```
02-10 19:02:54.567: D/WML_SISO(12014): InitPasteboardJni
02-10 19:02:54.577: W/webcore(12014): java.lang.Throwable: EventHub.removeMessages(int what = 107) is not supported before the WebViewCore is set up.
02-10 19:02:54.577: W/webcore(12014):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub.removeMessages(WebViewCore.java:2510)
02-10 19:02:54.577: W/webcore(12014):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub.access$12800(WebViewCore.java:1219)
02-10 19:02:54.577: W/webcore(12014):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.removeMessages(WebViewCore.java:2622)
02-10 19:02:54.577: W/webcore(12014):   at android.webkit.WebView.sendOurVisibleRect(WebView.java:3894)
02-10 19:02:54.577: W/webcore(12014):   at android.webkit.ZoomManager.setZoomScale(ZoomManager.java:976)
02-10 19:02:54.577: W/webcore(12014):   at android.webkit.ZoomManager.access$2100(ZoomManager.java:57)
02-10 19:02:54.577: W/webcore(12014):   at android.webkit.ZoomManager$PostScale.run(ZoomManager.java:1509)
02-10 19:02:54.577: W/webcore(12014):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
02-10 19:02:54.577: W/webcore(12014):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-10 19:02:54.577: W/webcore(12014):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-10 19:02:54.577: W/webcore(12014):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
02-10 19:02:54.577: W/webcore(12014):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-10 19:02:54.577: W/webcore(12014):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-10 19:02:54.577: W/webcore(12014):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:985)
02-10 19:02:54.577: W/webcore(12014):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:752)
02-10 19:02:54.577: W/webcore(12014):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Log cat will tell you exactly why. What does it say? In all likelihood you dont have the correct permission

Comment: I am not getting any error in logcat

Comment: I see you're catching your errors and just showing toast. Log the actually error so you can see the message supplied. For the most part Facebook's SDK is pretty good at explaining what went wrong in my experience

Comment: please see my edited post, I have given my Log output,and I am going inside publish cancelled Toast message

Comment: Wait is this actually a web page? Otherwise what you need is AlertDialog

Comment: I wants to post on my friends wall,but I am getting this error

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47175/discussion-between-user1891910-and-nick-cardoso)

Comment: hi, did you read this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/? Are you allowed to post to your friends wall or is this maybe restricted by your friend? Did you try a Facebook Webpage if your are allowed to do?

Comment: you cannot post on your friend's wall, not at least by this code. What i suggest is that you study Facebook GraphAPI, that may help. Can you also provide the link, where you read about this.